# Flex: Read values from Repeater

Tags: apache-flex, repeater, itemrenderer

I am using a simple Repeater which has a single component(TextInput).

```
    <mx:Repeater id="myrep" dataProvider="{myAC}" > 
        <local:TextInputRepeater id="tiRepeater" displaytext="{myrep.currentItem}" />
    </mx:Repeater>

    <mx:Button label="Get Data" click="getNewValues(event)" />
```

The repeater has following code:

```
[Bindable]
public var displaytext:String = "";

<mx:TextInput id="repeatText" text="{displaytext}" change="repeatText_changeHandler(event)"/>
```

Here is what I want : on click of button in getNewValues function, I want to read the values (user might possibly have changed in the textInputs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was a silly issue which I overlooked.

Solution is, tiRepeater[index] will give you the udpated repeater object.